# DNN and WSFederation - FedAuth cookie not being sent to server

Tags: cookies, dotnetnuke, ws-federation

I recently moved a DNN site a level down in my IIS.  Now single sign on doesn't work because the FedAuth cookie isn't being sent in the request.  If I set the CookieHandler.Path property to "/" it DOES work, but I have multiple sites in the IIS so this causes some conflict.

I have made the change in relyingparties from mysite.com to mysite.com/newspot/

I have also made the httpalias change in the dnn portalalias table to point to mysite.com/newspot

Is there some other variable that I need to change for this to work?  By default, the cookie's path is /newspot/ as it should be.  It's just not making it into the requests.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out.  The issue was the casing. mysite.com/PLACE/ is not the same as mysite.com/place/ when it comes to cookies.  So it was setting the cookie's path to mysite.com/newspot/ and then trying to find the cookie at mysite.com/NEWSPOT/ when this was fixed, everything started working as expected.